# How to fix a problem when user-defining goes wrong

Tags: python, function, if-statement, user-defined-functions

I am completely new to programming, now im struggling on a little program where the "grade" wont get defined. Thank you

I tried return grade but it wont work anyway

```
def computegrade(score,grade):
     try:
        if score >1.0001:
            grade= print("invalid score")
        elif score < -0.0001:
            grade= print("invalid score")
        elif score >= 0.9:
            grade= print("A")
        elif score >= 0.8:
            grade= print("B")
        elif score >= 0.7:
            grade= print("C")
        elif score >= 0.6:
            grade= print("D")
        elif score < 0.6:
            grade= print("F")
    except:
        print("Invalid")
    return grade

score=input("Enter your Score(between 0.0-1.0)\n")
grade=computegrade(score,grade)
```

Please fix the problem that "grade"  gets defined correctly.Thanks :)
When you enter e.g. 0.7,it says : grade=computegrade(score,grade)
NameError: name 'grade' is not defined

Comment: What means "won't work" here? Error message, if any (edit question to show it as properly defined text)?

Comment: Variables which are set in a function are by default local. They don't exist outside of that function.

Comment: You don’t define grade if an exception is tripped. You are trying to compare a string from input to an integer, which raises a type error

Answer (score 0):

1. You can assign print() to a variable, but its weird.
2. At the last line you are using the empty(not defined yet) variable "grade"
3. You don't really need the variable grade `computegrade(score, grade)`, you can declare it outside
4. You also need to convert the input variable(by default whatever you enter here is a string) to integer or float like in this case (int -> 1 - 5 - 9 - 0, float -> 1.5 - 2.58 - 3.9)

This should work:

```
def compute_grade(score):
    grade = ""
    try:
        if score >1.0001:
            grade= "invalid score"
        elif score < -0.0001:
            grade= "invalid score"
        elif score >= 0.9:
            grade= "A"
        elif score >= 0.8:
            grade= "B"
        elif score >= 0.7:
            grade= "C"
        elif score >= 0.6:
            grade= "D"
        elif score < 0.6:
            grade= "F"
    except:
        print("Invalid")
    return grade

score = float(input("Enter your Score (between 0.0-1.0)\n"))
grade = compute_grade(score)
print (grade)
```